# How to design a solution where have similar operation, example CRUD, but does not apply to all of its subclass

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, sharepoint-2010

I trying to design a solution to provide CRUD operation.
I am suppose to provide interfaces to several entities. Where each class are map to a single entity. Each class provide CRUD operation to each entity. However there are some entity that only provide certain operation. Such as Read and Update only, Create and Read only etc. 
How should i design such that I am able to better scale and create a good interface for other developer?

my current design :

```
5 Interface
IEntity, IReadItem, IDelete, ICreate, IUpdate.
Example IEntity -> Customer class
IReadList -> Read List Operations on Customer
IDelete-> Delete operation on Customer
ICreate -> Create Item operation on Customer
IUpdate -> Update Operation on customer

EntityFactory -> Instantiate the IEntity, and 4 operation concrete class.
 -> getEntity(EntityType(enum)) : return Concrete IEntity Class
 -> getReadList(ReadListType(enum),entity) : return concrete GetItemOperation Class
 -> getDelete(DeleteType(enum),entity) : return concrete DeleteItemOperation Class
 -> getCreate(CreateType(enum),entity) : return concrete CreateItemOperation Class

Entity -> Responislbe of caching own information and connection
Read,Create,Delete,Update -> Responsible of it own details and operation

Each entity have all or subset of the type 4 operation, CRUD.
```

Is there a better way to design this? or any comment on above layout?

Comment: tell me if my problem i mention update is not clear. I would try to define it clearer.

Comment: Why do you need interfaces and operation handles for the CRUD operations? What is the purpose of your design? You can't tell if there's a better design without knowing the reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to pick a well known existing design pattern for working with relational databases. Looking at your code its hard to determine which one you were going for. Once you settle on the appropiate pattern you might find it easier to find a solution.

You can read about some persistence options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569757.aspx#id0400052). Martin Fowler also shows several [on this page](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/) listed under **Data Source Architectural Patterns**.

Of course you also have the option of using an existing ORM such as Entity Framework or nHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Having asked for the actual design goals above... without more concrete goals I'd say keep it simple:

IEntity should have the Update and Delete methods and the factory the Read/List and Create methods. Entities/Factories which do not support the operation should throw an exception or return a meaningful value. That's it.